# Why does a forward slash with spaces around in my en.yml file break Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, translation, yaml

I have a rails app with a .yml file that holds translations which are used in the app by calling t(.my_text)

When I use text with a forward slash in it, for example "Be good / bad" The page does not seem to load. However when I remove the spaces ("Be good/bad") the page loads correctly and the text is shown.

Why could this be?

thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you know more about ruby than I do but it sounds like the " / " is syntactically important to strings.  have you tried escaping the slash?: `\\/`